# Comment exprimer « closed form solution »

Tags: traduction, mathématiques

Quelle est l'équivalent le plus courant de la tournure mathématique anglaise ci-dessous ?

> A closed-form solution.

Je pense aux tournures suivantes

> une solution analytique ;
>
> une solution explicite ;
>
> une solution à forme fermée ;
>
> une solution en forme analytique (ou fermée).

mais je me demande laquelle paraît plus francisée.

Comment: Tu es passé par [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_de_forme_ferm%C3%A9e) ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci pour votre commentaire. À vrai dire non:-)! Mais je suis passé par linguee et j'ai vu solution à forme fermée (et pas de). Je pense que wikipédia est plus fidèle, non ? Je trouve également la tournure solution en (de) forme close la plus soutenue, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On utilise le terme *forme close*. Dans votre exemple, on dira :

> Une solution de forme close.

C'est la formulation la plus répandue chez les mathématiciens, en tout cas en France. C'est peut-être différent pour les canadiens francophones. Elle est close au sens où elle est *finie*. Une expression non close est par exemple:

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ...

quand on l'utilise pour définir la somme infinie des nombres entiers positifs.