# « Système fermé » contre « système clos »

Tags: usage, synonymes, participe-passé, physique

Je me demande pourquoi on dit *système fermé* et pas *système clos* ou *clôturé* (le contexte est la thermodynamique et plus précisément concerne un système thermodynamique qui peut échanger de la chaleur ou du travail avec l'extérieur, mais pas de la matière). Dans les ouvrages thermodynamiques on rencontre *clôture* et pas *fermeture*. Clôture venant du verbe clôturer, ma confusion s’accroît.

Peut-être suis-je influencé par l'anglais *closed system*, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une explication.

Comment: Il est probable que *clôturer* vient de *clôture*, et non l'inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je me demande pourquoi on dit système fermé et non système clos ou clôturé.

Pour la même raison que les affichettes que l'on place à l'entrée d'un magasin indiquent **ouvert/fermé** (et pas **ouvert/clos**, et encore moins **ouvert/clôturé**) alors qu'en anglais, ce sera ***open/closed***.

L'antonyme naturel d'**ouvert** est **fermé**.

**Clos** est un synonyme de **fermé**, mais il est moins générique et s'emploie plus souvent dans des locutions figées (ex: le débat est clos, il a trouvé porte close, un vase clos, un procès à huis clos). Le verbe *clore* a d'ailleurs longtemps été délaissé à cause de son ancienne proximité phonétique avec *clouer*.

**Clôturé** semble moins indiqué que fermé ou clos car il a un sens plus spécialisé : au propre : « qui est entouré de clôtures » et au figuré : « qui est terminé, qui a pris fin ».

Comment: Merci ! On a parle aussi de *Une solution de forme close* (closed-form solution). https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/comment-exprimer-closed-form-solution

Comment: Oui. Il faut quand même faire attention car si *fermé/clos* et *fini* ont des sens proches, il n'en est pas toujours de même pour *ouvert* et *infini*.

Answer (score 1):

*Clôturé* dans ce contexte aura plus un sens de finalité, où on suppose un état précédent/antérieur *ouvert* comme dans *dossier clos*.

Par opposition, en thermodynamique ou en électricité par exemple on dirait *système fermé* ou *circuit fermé* (resp.) pour la description de l'état indépendamment des autres états possibles

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse très utile.

Answer (score 1):

Pour dire en d'autres termes ce que formule la réponse de jlliagre et ajouter un contexte et des exemples, cela est possiblement le résultat d'une tendance culturelle des sciences propre au français ;
on se sert beaucoup de cet adjectif  en science ;

- lignes courbes fermées en géométrie
- ensembles fermés en topologie
- circuits fermés en électricité et en électronique
- circuits fermés dans la technologie de la télévision
- systèmes fermés en économie

Comment: Merci ! En revanche  on dit solution de forme close.

Comment: @dimitris Dans quelle discipline ?

Comment: Mathématiques, non ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_de_forme_ferm%C3%A9e

Comment: @dimitris C'est appelé ainsi par opposition à une solution par des approximations alors, comme lorsque on retient *n* termes  de la série d'une fonction pour représenter cette dernière ?

Comment: En anglais on dit *closed-form solution* lorsque "An equation is said to be a closed-form solution if it solves a given problem in terms of functions and mathematical operations from a given generally-accepted set." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html Cherchant à trouver comment ça se traduit en français j'ai vu qu'en français on dit solution analytique, solution de forme fermée/close, en forme close, etc. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/comment-exprimer-closed-form-solution

Comment: @dimitris I did not need that, I got it all from your first link  (Wikipédia) ; thank you anyway!

Comment: Je t'en prie :-)! Ravi d'être utile